# Pandas loc with multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I wondering how to use pandas loc with multiple dataframes.
I have three dataframes and I need to filter these values( Note all dataframes have a different number of rows).

For example my code right now is slow and looks like this:

```
    df1['score'] = None
    df1['complited_activities'] = 0
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        values = df_enrollment.iloc[i]
        for j in range(len(df2)):
            df2_values = score_df.iloc[j]
            if values['fild_16'] == score_values['user_id'] and values['fild_15'] == score_values['course_id']:
                df1.iloc[i, df1.columns.get_loc('score')] = score_values['progress_score']
        for k in range(len(df3)):
            sub_values = df3.iloc[k]
            if values['fild_16'] == sub_values['user_id']:
                df1.iloc[i, df1.columns.get_loc('complited_activities')] = sub_values['count']
```

Here you can see that firstly program get row from df1 dataframe( values variable).
After that it get a row from df2 dataframe and check this statement(values['fild_16'] == score_values['user_id'] and values['fild_15'] == score_values['course_id']). If statement is true I set up value for column score using iloc .
After that same process for df3

How I can do this without this loops using something like loc?

```
df1
fild_16, fild_15, score, complited_activities
1,         14,      0          None
2,         15,      0          None
3,         16,      0          None
4,         17,      0          None
df2
user_id, course_id
15          14
2           15
3           16
df3
user_id,   score
135         145
2           42
4           412

Expected output:
fild_16, fild_15, score, complited_activities
1,         14,      0          None
2,         15,      1          42
3,         16,      1          None
4,         17,      0          412

In df1 fild_16 is user_id, fild_15 - course_id
```

Comment: kindly share sample data and expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy Shared